# Updating the class name of Div based on top position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Actually i am trying to achieve smooth scrolling in Jquery, and whatever code i have written seems to be working fine, but i also want to implement a feature where my Nav Class Changes to active when user scroll down/up based on the position. Below link to code will give you more idea on what i am talking about. problem i am facing is even though i click on the next nav sub element active class is set to previous element. i have user window.scroll of query infact this part is actually got it from net. i really dint understand the code that is why its hard fa me debug and fix it, so if anyone is able to fix it, it would be really good if you explain me what this code is actually doing and what is the problem with current implementation.

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqJmK

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var lastId,
    header = $("#header"),  
    topMenu = $("#nav"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+header.outerHeight()+25,
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    //menuItems = topMenu.find("a:not([href^='http://'],[href^='/'])"),
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });


    menuItems.on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        _this = this;
        var target = _this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        //menuItems.parent().removeClass("active");
        //$(_this).parent().addClass("active");
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': ($target.offset().top) - topMenuHeight + 1
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){

            var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

            var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
              if (($(this).offset().top +20)< fromTop){
                    return this;
                }
            });

              cur = cur[cur.length-1];

              var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
              if (lastId !== id) {
                lastId = id;
              menuItems
                .parent().removeClass("active")
                .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
            }           
    });

    /*$( window ).resize(function() {
            alert($( window ).width());
            alert($( document ).width());
    }); */


});
```

Comment: may be duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668411/adding-a-css-class-based-on-browser-scroll-position-with-jquery-looking-for-a/

Answer (score 0):

You might be best off using some sort of a plugin to achieve this effect. Something like http://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/ or http://www.outyear.co.uk/smint/demo/ would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Just update your scroll check function & make your position check little more flexible i.e let it consider that you entered a section little before it enters it. Make this change on line 35  in your code -

```
if (($(this).offset().top - 50)< fromTop)
```

**WORKING DEMO - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/LEAzI**

You can also improve your UI by implementing this - http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/